# Strategy for relating two rows of the same table together in MySQL on INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Suppose I have a simple MySQL table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  `my_table` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 8 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

I want to create two rows that are related to each other.   I've considered doing it two ways.

---

First strategy: Adding a "related_to" field to the table.

I am using AUTO_INCREMENT to calculate the ID, I'll need 5 steps to do this.

1. INSERT INTO `my_table` (`name`) VALUES ('abc');
2. Retrieve insert ID (let's call it $first_id)
3. INSERT INTO `my_table` (`name`, `related_to`) VALUES ('xyz', '$last_id');
4. Retrieve insert ID (let's call it $second_id)
5. UPDATE `my_table` SET `related_to` = '$second_id' WHERE `id` = '$first_id';

---

Second strategy: A separate table linking with both IDs.  Can do this in 5 steps as well.

1. INSERT INTO `my_table` (`name`) VALUES ('abc');
2. Retrieve insert ID (let's call it $first_id)
3. INSERT INTO `my_table` (`name`) VALUES ('xyz');
4. Retrieve insert ID (let's call it $second_id)
5. INSERT INTO `link_table` (`item1`,`item2`) VALUES ('$first_id', '$second_id');

---

Which way would be best in terms of efficiency, or is there an even more efficient way of doing it that I am missing?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a third column will be more efficient in terms of processing - queries will run slightly faster. 
Using a separate relationship will be more efficient in terms of memory usage - your database will occupy slightly less memory.

I'd be tempted to go for the relationship table because it results in a normalized design, although it will be a bit harder to work with.  It will avoid any issues you might have where the related_to values become out of sync.  For example, A and B are related to each other.  A has related_to=B, B has related_to=A.  This is duplicate data so requires a bit more management to keep consistent if you use a third column.

Depending on the volume of your data, it's unlikely that you'll have any real performance issues with either of these designs (the difference will be in terms of milliseconds), so you should probably take whichever feels more comfortable.

Comment: Actually, as long as the related_to field is a 1:1 relationship I would say that the first solution is the more normalized one. The relationship table would imply that a 1:many relationship exists.

Comment: @Jordy: Wait, if each field requires a value, we have redundant data in the third column because of the cyclic relationship. I'm not sure which is technically correct.

Comment: It will be a 1:1 relationship.  In terms of the "cyclic" relationship, I never know which row I will access first.  So I want to be able to directly have access to the id from there.   I suppose I could just do a search on the row for the related_to, but if I'm searching on a non-primary field, isn't it slower?

Answer (score 0):

Use a third column called related_to in which you store id from the firs query if B is only related to A (1-1 relation).

```
INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES ('abc');
Retrieve insert ID (let's call it $first_id)
INSERT INTO my_table (name, related_to) VALUES ('xyz', '$first_id');
```

If B can be related to A, C,D,... and A can be related to B and C and... use an extra table like (1-many OR many-many relation):

INSERT INTO link_table (item1_id,item2_id) VALUES ('$first_id', '$second_id');

Answer (score 0):

Where you choose one of the above, or somethind different, to handle this issue, this is a design choice and I think there are bigger factors in the choice than counting steps like youve done.

> Is this relationship symmetric?
>   Is it transitive?
>   Is it a parent child kind of thing?
>   Are the entries really similar enough to belong in the same table?

By renaming to 'my_table' and showing only id and name fields you've pretty much hidden most of whats going on here.  What I can tell you is that when making your choice you have a lot more to consider than counting whats involved in the insert.  What about when you query it later and you want to get all the rows associated with another row?  Are there update/deletion anomolies? etc.

Possible solutions incldue both of what you suggested.  You also might have a `type` field along with a `type` table, in which these rows fall into one of several categories and all rows in the same category are 'related'

```
1. related_to field
2. many-to-many table
3. type/category field
4. parent-child hierarchy (there are many potential solutions for this)
```

This depends more on the nature of the relationship than what steps are involved in the insert.  First of all, you will likely be selecting way more often than you insert.  Also, depending on whether or not these rows are likely to come in groups you might consider a stored procedure for the insertion and that renders those counts moot.

Comment: I was just trying to simplify the amount of data that I was showing, but I'll go ahead and tell you what the table is for.  The table is for buyers and cobuyer of a vehicle. Due to the context of the software, I can't really tie the buyers to a "vehicle" per-say, but really only care about the buyer/cobuyer being related to each other.   I realize that "counting steps" isn't necessarily more efficient.  I just broke it down that way, for an easier break down and explanation.

Comment: @David: This model is flawed - what if there are 3 co-buyers?

Comment: @Greg.  Generally, I'd agree with you, but the client has said there will only be 2 in the context of this project. I'll probably prepare for the 1:N relationship anyways, just because I have a feeling they'll probably change their minds down the road anyways.  I was more trying to see if their would be any benefit from using the other means.